# Form is getting submit without 'action' and '@modelAttribut'?

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc

If I click on a button then form is getting submit and surprisingly there are no errors but my question is  like How a form can get submitted  without any attributes for 'form' tag?

I am supposed to write the form tag like:

```
<form:Form action="upcomingLeaves.do" commandName="loginform" modelAttribute="loginform"
method="POST">
....
.....
<form:form>
```

I wrote like this:

```
<form:form>       
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr style="background-color:#666633;">
              <th>Employee id</th>
              <th>Leave Balance</th>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Leave Type</th>
              <th>Leave Period</th>
              <th>Applied Leaves</th>
              <th>Status</th>
              <th colspan="4">Action</th>
        </tr></thead>
      <tbody>
      <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${not empty upcomingLeavesList}">
            <c:forEach items="${upcomingLeavesList}" var="upComLeave">
                <tr>
                    <td><span>${upComLeave.employee_id}</span></td>
                    <td><span>${upComLeave.no_of_leave}</span></td>
                    <td><span>${upComLeave.fromDate} - ${upComLeave.toDate}</span></td>
                    <td><span>${upComLeave.leaveType}</span></td>
                    <td><span>${upComLeave.leavePeriod}</span></td>
                    <td><span>${upComLeave.appliedLeave}</span></td>
                    <td id="status"><span>${upComLeave.leaveStatus}</span></td>


                    <c:if test="${upComLeave.leaveStatus eq 'Pending' }"> <!-- check status if accepted, don't render Accept button -->
                             <td><button id="btnAccept" name="action"  value="Accept${upComLeave.employee_id}">Accept</button></td>
                            <td><button id="btnReject" name="action"  value="Reject${upComLeave.employee_id}">Reject</button></td>
                    </c:if>


                    <c:if test="${upComLeave.leaveStatus eq 'Approved' }"> <!-- check status if accepted, don't render Accept button -->
                             <td><button id="btnCancel" name="action"  value="Cancel${upComLeave.employee_id}">Cancel</button></td>
                    </c:if>
                    <c:if test="${upComLeave.leaveStatus eq 'Canceled' }"> <!-- check status if accepted, don't render Accept button -->
                             <td><button id="btnAccept" name="action"  value="Accept${upComLeave.employee_id}">Accept</button></td>
                    </c:if>
                    <c:if test="${upComLeave.leaveStatus eq 'Rejected' }"><!-- //check status if accepted, don't render Reject button -->
                        <td><button id="btnReject" name="action" value="Reject${upComLeave.employee_id}">Reject</button></td>
                    </c:if>
                   <%--  <c:if test="${upComLeave.leaveStatus eq 'Canceled' }"><!-- //check status if cancel, render cancel button -->
                        <td><button id="btnAccept" name="action"  value="Accept${upComLeave.employee_id}">Cancel</button></td>
                    </c:if> --%>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            upcomingLeavesList is empty or null..
        </c:otherwise>
      </c:choose>

      </tbody>      

  </table>
 </form:form>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upcomingLeaves" ,method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String ApproveLeaves(@RequestParam(required=false , defaultValue="")String aion,@RequestParam(required=false,defaultValue="")String Cancel,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ModelMap model){...}
```

After clicking on the button form should not submit,right?to do that task I use ajax so I would write ajax code for ex:

```
   $('button').on('click',function(event){

                    // get the form values

                    var str = $("#loginform").serialize();



             event.preventDefault();

                    $.ajax({

                    type: "POST",

                    url:"upcomingLeaves.do",

                    data: str,

                    success: function(response){

                    // we have the response
             alert("Did it....");
               window.location.reload(true);



                    $('#Status').val('');



                    },

                    error: function(e){

                    alert('Error: ' + e);

                    }

                    });

                    });
```

Is ajax code right?
Please Help me.......

Comment: Your question is very unclear to me. *"I wrote the form like this..."*, *"but I'm supposed to be writing it as..."*. So just write the form like you're supposed to. A form without attributes will act on defaults. Also `modelAttribute` and `commandName` are the same thing. Use `modelAttribute` since it's the most descriptive one.

Comment: okay I will edit the question.Please Describe your answer .Thank you.